# regex with multiline doesn't match with pattern written

Tags: java, regex, match, multiline, regex-group

In return to a modem read request I'm getting a text message with format attached below.
I'm trying using regex multiline to store different information like cell number, date, my logger name(AUTO-1), value in hex and this last two are in a different line.

This is my Pattern to read multiline string, but unfortunately it doesn't match.

```
private static final String REGEX_EMPTY_LINE = ".*\\s";
private static final String REGEX_NUMBER_DATE_TIME = ".*\".*\",\"(.*)\",\".*\",\"(.*)\"\\s";
private static final String REGEX_OK = ".*";
private static final String REGEX_LETTURA = ".*\"(.*)\"([E|T|V])_([0-9A-F]{3})_([0-9A-F]{3})_([b|B])_(.{22})([0-9A-F]{2})";
private static final Pattern READ_REGEX = Pattern.compile(REGEX_EMPTY_LINE + REGEX_NUMBER_DATE_TIME + REGEX_LETTURA + REGEX_EMPTY_LINE + REGEX_EMPTY_LINE + REGEX_OK, Pattern.MULTILINE);


String raw="\r\n+CMGR: \"REC READ\",\"+393355222692\",\"\",\"13/07/09,15:46:31+08\"\r\n>\"AUTO-1\"T_11C_000_B_----------------------20\r\r\n\r\nOK\r\n";

Matcher matcher = READ_REGEX.matcher(raw);
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("Match");
}
```

[image: This is my string]

Comment: Specify what you want to match and also what @Dukeling said

Comment: I would like to match: 1-Phone number, 2-Date-time, 3-Logger name(AUTO-1), 4-type (T), 5-Value (11C hex), 6-B (value battery), 7-20(checksum)

Comment: I have correct the post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your string uses `"\r\n"` for a newline, but your pattern for a newline seems to be `"\\s"`, which only matches one character.  instead you should use `"\\s{2}"`.

Comment: @AlessandroMattiuzzi - huh?  if you want to match the newline string, you need _two_ characters.

Comment: @AlessandroMattiuzzi - i did help you, i put the solution in my answer.

Comment: String r1 = ".*\"(.*)\",\"(.*)\",\"\",\"(.*)\"";
String r2 = ".*\"(.*)\"([E|T|V])_([0-9A-F]{3})_([0-9A-F]{3})_([b|B])_(.{22})([0-9A-F]{2})";
String p = "("+r1+")\\s+("+r2+")\\s+OK";

Comment: this works for me. Can you please vote my question. Thank you for your reply.